# GlassFish change port of web-service

Tags: java, port, glassfish, web-services

I am new to Java and Linux.
I have a JSP site and a java web service deployed on a GlassFish server (working OK).

I need to change the port of both the application and web-service.

I have changed the listener port in the domain.xml file, but the web application is still trying to connect to the WSDL on port 8080.

How can I change the configuration of the web service port?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wrap this up, it probably belongs more in StackOverflow rather than ServerFault as it is code related...

The problem was that the code of the application went to the original web-service and was not changeable via any configuration change.

I sorted the issue on basis of the code I found at: [totd_2_change_the_endpoint](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/totd_2_change_the_endpoint)
and [ibm.com/developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-javaclient/index.html)
which I used to create the QName object.

@KPWINC: Thanks for the time and effort!